# What Is The Difference Between BUTTON1_MASK and BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK?

Tags: java, input

From the java website:

```
BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK = The Mouse Button1 extended modifier constant.
BUTTON1_MASK = The Mouse Button1 modifier constant.
```

I'm not even sure what a "modifier constant" is. Let alone an extended one.
I do understand however that `BUTTON1_MASK` is just the integer representation for when the left mouse button is clicked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`BUTTON1_MASK` is the mask indicating an event came from button 1.  `BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK` is conceptually similar, but is the **extended** version of that constant.

There are two methods that return such sets of constants: `InputEvent#getModifiers()` and `InputEvent#getModifiersEx()`, and they will return modifier constants, or *extended* modifier constants, respectively.

[From the docs (bold is mine)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html):

> The button mask returned by InputEvent.getModifiers() reflects only
>   the button that changed state, not the **current** state of all buttons
>   ... To get the state of all buttons and modifier
>   keys, use InputEvent.getModifiersEx().

[and also (bold is mine)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getModifiersEx%28%29):

> **Extended modifiers** represent the state of all modal keys, such as ALT,
>   CTRL, META, and the mouse buttons just **after** the event occurred
>
> For example, if the user presses button 1 followed by button 2, and
>   then releases them in the same order, the following sequence of events
>   is generated:
>
> ```
> MOUSE_PRESSED:  BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK
> MOUSE_PRESSED:  BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK | BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK
> MOUSE_RELEASED: BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK
> MOUSE_CLICKED:  BUTTON2_DOWN_MASK
> MOUSE_RELEASED:
> MOUSE_CLICKED:
> ```

If all you want is to detect a button 1 (normally, left) click, then either of these should work:

```
if ((e.getModifiers() & MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) != 0) {
    System.out.println("BUTTON1_MASK");
}

if ((e.getModifiersEx() & MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK) != 0) {
    System.out.println("BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK");
}
```

Also, you can check out this open source version of `InputEvent`, [which has some more useful comments, and shows what's happening inside](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-1640/libjava/java/awt/event/InputEvent.java)

Comment: It has been a LONG time but incase anyone reads this: why in your code is there the single ampersand? i.e. e.getModifiers() & MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK. Is that representing a set intersection?

Comment: @user2316667, that's because the `getModifiers()` and [getModifiersEx()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#getModifiersEx%28%29) methods return an integer, that can hold a *combination* of flags.  To test for any **one** particular flag in an integer, you use the `&` operator to see if that particular bit is nonzero (that's where the `!= 0` comes from).  So, if the Button1 bit is what you're interested in, you check for that with a mask like `e.getModifiers() & BUTTON1_MASK != 0`.  This isn't the boolean `&&` operator ... that's something different.

Comment: [See this tutorial for more](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm) on operators like the "bitwise AND".

Comment: The last link is dead.

Comment: @FDinoff, thanks.  I believe I found [another one](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-1640/libjava/java/awt/event/InputEvent.java), which has the same useful comments on `getModifiers()`.  Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

As the docs state, `BUTTON1_MASK` and `BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK` are modifier constants, i.e. they are use in conjunction with `MouseEvent#getModifiers`. They are not extended but rather used as a mask values, for example

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
 if ((me.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) == InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) {
      System.out.println("Left button pressed.");
    }
}
```

`BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK` is used to detect the state of the mouse button whereas the `BUTTON1_MASK` simply helps to determine which button is pressed.

Comment: This answer is concise.