# KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK vs KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

What's the difference between `KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK` and `KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK`?
The Javadoc says that "It is recommended that SHIFT_DOWN_MASK be used instead".

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16410228/230513).

Comment: I think the difference between `getModifiers()` and `getModifiersEx()` is key and explained well in @trashgod's linked comment.  (What are all of the mods currently held down, versus what changed just now to generate the event.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK) as binary numbers, you'll see that they form a complete [bitset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) from 2<sup>0</sup> though 2<sup>13</sup>. The `*_MASK` values form the lower range, and the `*_DOWN_MASK` form the upper. They all have the same recommendation, with the latter superseding the former.

Addendum: @Boann comments, "This states that they're different. It doesn't explain why."

I am relucatnt to speculate, but I think it's reasonable to infer that the developers needed to accommodate extended modifiers, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16410228/230513), while preserving backward compatibility.

Comment: This states that they're different. It doesn't explain why.